# change datetime object to string

Tags: python, datetime, timestamp, strftime

I want to convert `datetime.datetime(2016, 11, 21, 5, 34, 38, 826339, tzinfo=<UTC>)`  as `Nov. 21, 2016, 11:04 a.m.`

The time in the datetime object is in UST but I want it to be converted into IST(UST+ 05:30).

I tried using **strftime** as:

```
 >>> datetime(2016, 11, 21, 5, 34, 38, 826339, tzinfo=<UTC>).isoformat(' ')
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    datetime(2016, 11, 21, 5, 34, 38, 826339, tzinfo=<UTC>).isoformat(' ')
                                                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Can I get some help here.

PS: I am using python

EDIT:

```
cr_date = datetime(2016, 11, 21, 5, 34, 38, 826339) #excluding the timezone
```

I can get partial desired reults by:

```
cr_date.strftime('%b. %d, %Y %H:%M')
'Oct. 31, 2013 18:23
```

didn't get the am/pm though

Answer (score 0):

For the am/pm part, couldn't you use %p for the last field? I don't know python, I'm just assuming python is taking syntax from the unix date command.

Answer (score 0):

add `%p` for 'AM or PM' else add `%P` for 'am or pm'

Answer (score 0):

Please find below code

```
from datetime import datetime
cr_date = datetime(2016, 11, 21, 5, 34, 38, 826339)
cr_date.strftime('%b. %d, %Y %H:%M %P')
'Nov. 21, 2016 05:34 am'
```